# Is there a link between Imposter Phenomenon and dreams of unfulfilled ambitions?

Tags: psychology, dreams

*Imposter Syndrome* is a popular topic in both scientific studies and pop-psychology articles. Less common is *Imposter Phenomenon*, wherein an attempt is made to be more conscientious about the subject. I have not done any extensive searches, but will accept [this review article's conclusion](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.00671/full) that better research methodology to is needed to validate it and any corresponding comorbities. Knowing that it's not been studied rigorously enough to meet the review article's recommendations, I'll use the concept (and ask the question) anyway.

Most doctors I know/knew have "Imposter Syndrome", limiting it for now to a feeling that they are, and have a fear of being exposed for being, less competent than they, in fact and measurably, are. For years I attributed this to the realization that it's impossible to know everything they "should" know (which is why specialists and referrals exist.) The only doctors I know who have not experienced this have been/were clinically diagnosed (not by me) with Narcissistic Personality Disorder (N=4).

This is a highly viewed xkcd comic strip:

[image]

Interestingly it implies a near-universality between higher education (a must for all physicians/other professionals) and dreams of somehow failing in that education, and the articles linked below affirm this. One psychoanalyst opined that under stress, we naturally return to the most stressful times in our lives, implying school fills that role.

My question is, what is the basis of this dream (if there is any consensus) and is it linked in any way to "Imposter Syndrome"? Why is the dream about an academic failure?

<sub>Interestingly, I read that some professors are eliminating final exams based on the ubiquity of this dream. It will be interesting if this has an impact on the dream, though the studies may never be done and N will be small.</sub>

<sub>I've had some version of the exam dream for decades, yet college wasn't a time of particular stress for me; I never met a subject in Biology that I didn't love to study. On the other hand, my years in the Emergency Department, where lives could be lost if the wrong decision was made, *were* stressful, occasionally *extremely* so. Yet I never dream of not knowing what to do in an emergency. This seems to imply something particular about education.</sub>

[You’re at the final exam and never attended class. It’s that dream again.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/youre-at-the-final-exam-and-never-attended-class-its-that-dream-again/2016/09/19/01255a6c-792f-11e6-beac-57a4a412e93a_story.html)
[Recurring Final Exam Dream?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/radical-teaching/200909/recurring-final-exam-dream)